# access variable from within foreach loop in vue.js

Tags: javascript, foreach, vue.js, vuejs2, var

how do I access this.variable from a foreach loop?

I have like this

```
<template><div><li>{{ names }}</li></div></template>
var initData = {
  names: '',
  }
}
export default {
  data: function () {
    return initData
  },
  props: ['nameData'],
  methods: {
    printNames: function () {
      let tempData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.nameData))
      tempData.biglist.forEach(function (nObj) {
        let cName = nObj.CeName
        console.log(cName) // gives long list of names
        this.names = cName
      })
    }
  },
```

So what I want is to have the names in my list. Thanks people :)

Comment: share any live snippet/ demo ? nothing is clear with the code you provided.

Comment: you can define before function `var me= this` and inside `forEach()` you can access using `me.variable`.

Comment: 1. What `names` property is `this.names` supposed to set? 2. Note that it will get overwritten repeatedly, as you have it in the `forEach` callback. 3. Note that `this` will be either `undefined` (strict mode) or the global object (loose mode) because you're using a traditional function as the callback and not specifying a `this` value `forEach` should use. You may want an arrow function, but it's impossible to say from what you've shown.

Comment: T.J Crowder. yes I should be putting all thenames in to object value right? and then getting them each with v-for loop

I'm not sure hiw to do that though (yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is two way you can access this inside another function scope (in this case forEach() ).

You can simple create a new variable referencing your scope, like

```
printNames: function () {
  let scope = this
  let tempData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.nameData))
  tempData.biglist.forEach(function (nObj) {

    // I can access scope here

    let cName = nObj.CeName
    console.log(cName) // gives long list of names
    this.names = cName
  })
}
```

, and you will have access to this variable scope inside forEach.

Or you can use arrow functions, which does not create a new scope. Therefore, same `this` as outside the forEach. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2eAqE/1149/